# Jacobian and vectorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Given the matrix function $h(Q) = Q^{T}AQ$.

The derivative can be obtained as

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{h(Q - \epsilon H)-h(Q)}{\epsilon} = H^{T} A Q + Q^{T} A H$$

Then, I saw that the Jacobian $J_h(vec(Q)) = ((AQ)^{T} \otimes I)\Pi + I \otimes Q^{T} A$. I have some issues with obtaining this identity. Notice that $\Pi$ is the matrix s.t. $\Pi vec(X) = vec(X^{T}) \ \forall X$.

I tried this:

\begin{align*}
vec(H^{T} A Q + Q^{T} A H) &= vec(H^{T} A Q) + vec(Q^{T} A H)\\
&= (Q^{T} \otimes H^{T}) vec(A) + (H^{T} \otimes Q^{T}) vec(A)\\
&= (Q^{T} \otimes I) (I \otimes H^{T}) vec(A) + (H^{T} \otimes I)(I \otimes Q^{T})vec(A)\\
&= (Q^{T} \otimes H^{T}) vec(A) + (H^{T} \otimes Q^{T})vec(A)\\
&= ((Q^{T} \otimes H^{T}) + (H^{T} \otimes Q^{T})) vec(A).
\end{align*}

I am afraid that I am missing up something in the beginning, since there's no need for me to use $\Pi$. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You keep writing a sum instead of a product. You should replace each `\oplus` with `\otimes`

Comment: @BenGrossmann, ohh, I just realized now!

Comment: Please use `\operatorname{vec}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a function with a matrix input and matrix output does not, technically speaking, have a Jacobian. What it seems that you're actually interested in here is the Jacobian of the related function $f$ that takes a vector input and vector output such that $f(\operatorname{vec}(Q)) = \operatorname{vec}(h(Q))$. That is, you're interested in the Jacobian of the "vectorized version" of $h$.

In order to go from the Frechet/total derivative of a function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ to a Jacobian, you need to write the function $df(q):\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ (for $q \in \Bbb R^n$) in the form $M(q) \Delta q$ for some matrix $M$ depending on $q$. This matrix $M(q)$ is the Jacobian of the function $f$.

In other words, the relationship between the Jacobian of $f$ and the Frechet/total derivative of $f$ is that
$$
df(x)(h) = J_f(x)h, \quad x,h \in \Bbb R^n.
$$
Note that $h$ in the above is a vector rather than a function.

In your case, you have found that
$$
dh(Q)(\Delta Q) = \Delta Q^TAQ + Q^TA\Delta Q.
$$
If we define $f$ so that $f(\operatorname{vec}(Q)) = \operatorname{vec}(h(Q))$, then it follows that
\begin{align}
df(\operatorname{vec}(Q))(\operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q)) &= \operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q^TAQ + Q^TA\Delta Q)
\\ & = \operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q^TAQ)
+ \operatorname{vec}(Q^TA\Delta Q)
\\ & = [(AQ)^T \otimes I] \operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q^T) + 
[I \otimes (Q^TA)] \operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q)
\\ & = [(AQ)^T \otimes I] \Pi\operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q) + 
[I \otimes (Q^TA)] \operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q)
\\ & = \left[((AQ)^T \otimes I) \Pi + (I \otimes Q^TA)\right]\operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q)
\end{align}
Replacing $\operatorname{vec}(Q)$ with $q$ and $\operatorname{vec}(\Delta Q)$ with $\Delta q$ in the above gives us
$$
df(q)(\Delta q) = \left[((AQ)^T \otimes I) \Pi + (I \otimes Q^TA)\right] \Delta q.
$$
Thus, the Jacobian of $f$ (the vectorized version of $h$) is given by
$$
J_f = ((AQ)^T \otimes I) \Pi + (I \otimes Q^TA).
$$

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated. I have spent some time going through it now, and I have learned a lot. Unfortunately I can't upvote. But I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Do you have any references regarding the two identities $f(vec(Q))=vec(h(Q))$ and $d_f (x) (h) = J_f (x) h$. At last, what exactly is $\Delta$ in this situation.

Comment: $\Delta Q$ is a matrix and $\Delta q$ is a vector; $\Delta$ means nothing on its own. $\Delta x$ is meant to denote the "change in $x$" for some object $x$. No, I don't have a reference. $f({\rm vec}(Q)) = {\rm vec}(h(Q))$ is a definition, not an "identity" that requires proof.

Comment: I guess my confusion stems from the sudden introduction of $\Delta$. Obtaining the Frechet derivative doesn't include Delta, and then suddenly you say that $dh(Q) (\Delta Q)= \Delta Q^T A Q + Q^T A \Delta Q$, and why are we allowed to replace $vec(Q)$ with $q$ and $vec(\Delta Q)$ with $\Delta q$?

Comment: Ahh of course Delta Q is just H ?

Comment: Yes, I used $\Delta Q$ in the same way that you used $H$

Answer (score 0):

By substituting I brute forced my way to the identity. Although I am not sure why I am supposed to apply the perfect shuffle matrix and then divide by $vec(H)$.

From $H^{T} A Q + Q^{T} A H$, then put $\kappa = AQ$ and $\lambda = Q^{T}A$ Then:

\begin{align*}
vec(H^{T} \kappa) + vec(\lambda H) &= (\kappa^{T} \otimes I) vec(H^{T}) + (I \oplus \lambda) vec(H)\\
&= ( \kappa^{T} \otimes I) \Pi vec(H) + (I \otimes \lambda) vec(H)
\end{align*}
Then apparently one has to divide by $vec(H)$ to obtain

\begin{align*}
(\kappa^{T} \otimes I) \Pi + (I \otimes \lambda)
= ((AQ)^{T} \otimes I) \Pi + I \otimes Q^{T} A
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Using the more standard $K$ $($instead of $\Pi)$ to denote the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix#2), an uppercase $H$ to denote your $h$ matrix, lowercase letters $(h,q)$ to denote the vectorized form of the matrices $(H,Q),\,$ and using differentials instead of limits, the calculation runs as follows
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\v{\operatorname{vec}}
 H &= Q^TAQ \\
dH &= dQ^TAQ \;+\; Q^TA\,dQ \\
\v(dH) &= ((AQ)^T\k I)\v(dQ^T) \;+\; (I\k Q^TA)\v(dQ) \\
dh &= (Q^TA^T\!\k I)K\,dq \;+\; (I\k Q^TA)\,dq \\
\frac{\p h}{\p q} &= (Q^TA^T\!\k I)K \;+\; (I\k Q^TA) \\
}$$